# Validation summary with AJAX form in partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have an application that uses an AJAX form. When that form posts and validation fails, I return the partial view that the form is in. I would expect the Validation Summary to display, but it doesn't. I confirmed that the model is not valid (it hits the return PartialView("EditorTemplates/PanesViewModel", model) line), but when the partial view is returned, the Validation Summary does not display. Am I missing something?

I have the following code:

Index View

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "content",
    LoadingElementId = "loading"
}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div id="content">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Panes, "EditorTemplates/PanesViewModel")
    </div>
}
```

PanesViewModel

```
<fieldset>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <table>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.List, "EditorTemplates/ListViewModel")
        </table>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
```

ListViewModel

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items, "EditorTemplates/ItemViewModel")
```

ItemViewModel

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FieldName)</td>
</tr>
```

MyController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(PanesViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do stuff
        return PartialView("EditorTemplates/PanesViewModel");
    }

    // Should retain model state and display Validation Summary.
    return PartialView("EditorTemplates/PanesViewModel", model);
}
```

Comment: Not tested, but I suspect the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` needs to go inside `PanesViewModel`

Comment: I originally had it there (and I just tried again), and it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still a little unclear as to *why* exactly this fixed the issue, but it did:

I put the entire AJAX form in a Partial View, then called that Partial View with @Html.Partial in the Index view and returned PartialView("_Partial") in my controller actions. I'm guessing that the AJAX form needed to be inside the "thing" being reloaded (the partial view), rather than the EditorFor code that's *inside* the AJAX form being refreshed and the AJAX form itself being left alone.